# "Joseph visits Beneatha after she learns that Walter had lost the money in an investment opportunity."

Tags: verbs, modal-verbs, phrasal-verbs, subject-verb-agreement, auxiliary-verbs

Is had appropriate in the below sentence?

> Joseph visits Beneatha after she learns that Walter had lost the money in an investment opportunity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't required, because there is no past event, after the money loss but before Joseph's visit, to trigger it.

I will simplify your example - it doesn't need a woman named either Joseph or Beneatha to explain the tense.

No *had* needed:

> A visits B after she learns that he lost money.

*Had* needed:

> A visited B after she learned that he had lost money before they first met.

In this example with *had*, the time of losing the money is before their first meeting.

Comment: "Had" is not required, but it is allowed.

Comment: As a BrE speaker, I would say '...that he _has_ lost money...'.